# Why is only the first item printing

Tags: python

Wondering why when I write return arg after the for loop, I get the whole list I put in, but when I return reverse, only the last value in the list I provide prints

```
def reverse_complement(**seqs):
   for arg in seqs.values():
      reverse=arg[::-1]
   return reverse

print(reverse_complement(a='CGTC', b='ATATAT', c='TATA', d='GCGTCGC'))
```

gives :

```
CGCTGCG
```

Comment: your reverse is placed out of the loop so obviously will work on the last value provided.

Comment: You output is reverse of `d`. Tha’s what your reverse_complement does - it only returns the last element in seqs, reversed, so it returns d, reversed.

Comment: be careful that the loop is *NOT* supposed to give you `a, b, c, d` in this order (as it is in a dictionary in python).

Answer (score 0):

**Store the results in a `list` and retund the `list`.**

### Use this:

```
def reverse_complement(**seqs):
   results=[]
   for arg in seqs.values():
      reverse=arg[::-1]
      results.append(reverse)
   return results

print(reverse_complement(a='CGTC', b='ATATAT', c='TATA', d='GCGTCGC'))

['CTGC', 'ATAT', 'TATATA', 'CGCTGCG']
```

Comment: Good idea to add distringuishing messages in your print values, so the OP can tell that the first four lines are printed inside the function, and the return vaue is only the revered last element `d`

Answer (score -1):

To return the whole sequence (with the keys), return a dict:

```
def reverse_complement(**seqs):
   reverse_dict = {}
   for key in seqs.keys():
      arg = seqs[key]
      reverse_dict[key] = arg[::-1]
   return reverse_dict

print(reverse_complement(a='CGTC', b='ATATAT', c='TATA', d='GCGTCGC'))
```

This gives:

```
{'a': 'CTGC', 'c': 'ATAT', 'b': 'TATATA', 'd': 'CGCTGCG'}
```

as the output.